# Tree without any Null leaf in C

Tags: c, data-structures, tree

i need to create a BNF tree with nodes that have 3 children 2 children 1 child and 0 child and ı have to create different structs for each of them because there shouldn't be a any edge that points to null, but ı can't grasp the concept actually because ı used to do this stuff with only one structure and pointing the unused leaf to null any idea,hint,guidance would be appretiaced it.

Comment: Where do these requirements come from? Sounds weird. Also, just to make sure: is it a C assignment or C++? 'd like to know if inheritance could be used.

Comment: It is C assignment, they said that we can store children with void* data type but then how can ı type cast them and access it,that is the big question in my mind, i didn't came across anything like that so it is really confusing for me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One possible solution could be to use a tagged structure with a union.

Something like

```
enum NodeType
{
    NODE_LEAF, // A leaf node, no children
    NODE_1,    // One child
    NODE_2,    // Two children
    NODE_3     // Three children
};

struct Node
{
    enum NodeType type;

    union
    {
        struct
        {
            // TODO: Data for leaf nodes
        } leaf;

        struct
        {
            struct Node *child;  // One and only child
        } node_1;

        struct
        {
            struct Node *children[2];  // Two children
        } node_2;

        struct
        {
            struct Node *children[3];  // Three children
        } node_3;
    };
};
```

Then depending on the value of `type` you use the `leaf`, `node_1`, `node_2` or `node_3` union members.

Answer (score 0):

Like in the other answer you need an enum to determine the type of each node.

```
enum NodeType
{
    NODE_LEAF, // A leaf node, no children
    NODE_1,    // One child
    NODE_2,    // Two children
    NODE_3     // Three children
};
```

Then define structs for each node type that all have a common prefix:

```
struct NodeLeaf {
    NodeType type;
    ...
};
struct Node1 {
    NodeType type;
    NodeType *child[1];
};
struct Node2 {
    NodeType type;
    NodeType *child[2];
};
struct Node3 {
    NodeType type;
    NodeType *child[3];
};
```

The child pointers point to one of the structs, which all begin with a NodeType. Conveniently I already gave them `NodeType *` as type instead of `void *` to make is easier to read the type. You can then cast each child to the right struct depending on what is in *child[n]. And to assign a child cast the relevant struct to `NodeType*` or use `foo.child[0] = &bar.type;`.